# How does recording a macro differ from defining a macro directly?

Tags: macro, register

In my Vim configuration, I have mapped the `<C-j>` key to `<cmd>bn<CR>`, but because the `C-j` key corresponds to the null character in Vim, this causes some strange issues when defining macros. For instance, if I define a macro for `q` with

```
qq<CR>q
```

the macro executes the keystroke `<CR>`, as expected. But if I try to define `@q` directly with the keystrokes,

```
:let @q='^M'<CR>
```

where `^M` is the literal newline character, executing `q` with `@q` behaves like `<CR><C-j>`. And indeed, checking `:reg` shows that `"q=^M^J` when defined directly, and `"q=^M` when defined via macro recording. It seems like this extra null character is only appended when the string ends in a carriage return.

I would like to be able to define `"q` directly without this terminating null character. My solution for now has been to replace `^M$` with `^M^[`. While this works for virtually all cases, it's not perfect (for instance, if the macro ends in the middle of a chord, the `<nop>` would exit the chord).

Why does assignment and macro recording differ in this way? And is there a way to perform
assign a register without this terminating null character?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason is that when you set the register using the `let @q=` syntax, if it ends with `^M` or `^J` (`<CR>` or `<NL>`) the register is considered line wise (instead of character wise) and and `^J` is added at its end.

see `:help :let-@`

If you want to programmatically set register `q` to `^M` you can do:

```
setreg('q', '^M', 'c')
```

Comment: `setreg` works! Thank you!