# How to prevent an extra newline from being appended to macros ending with a newline?

Tags: command-line, macro, variables, line-breaks

If I save a macro by typing:

```
:let @s='/{<C-v><C-m>'<Enter>
```

which looks like:

```
:let @s='/{^M'
```

the macro that is actually saved is `/{^M^M`,
with an extra linebreak (that I did not type) appended at the end,
and not `/{^M` (which I intended).

This can be seen by running the macro (`@s`),
or by pasting the macro in the command-line mode by typing:

```
:let @s='<C-r>s'
```

What appears is:

```
:let @s='/{^M^M'
```

and not what I had originally wrote, which is:

```
:let @s='/{^M'
```

This only happens when I write macros in command-line mode,
and not when I create macros with `q`.

I did a bit of testing and this seems to be the case
with any macro ending with `^M`.

What is the reason for this behavior,
and how do I disable it?

I am using VIM 9.0 on Linux.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38262/23502) could help you?

Answer (score 0):

Others might be able to explain *why*, but using a literal `<Nul>` instead of a literal `<CR>` works:

```
:let @s = '/{<C-v><C-j>'<CR>
:reg s
Type name Content
  l  "s   /{^J
```

Frankly, the logic behind Vim's "handling" of `<Nul>`, `<NL>`, and `<CR>` has always been a bit of a puzzle for me. Committing arbitrary rules like "use `\n` for search and `\r` for replacement" kind of works for the day-to-day editing but it has never been intellectually satisfying.